# Can't create a variable in a while loop in VBScript?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

This code causes an error for me:

```
i = 0
Set colors = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do While i < 7
    If True Then
        Dim a(1)
        a(0) = "go"
        a(1)  = "tRY"
        colors.Add "space", a
    End If
    i = i + 2
Loop
```

I'm not too sure why. I need to do something similar, where I initialize a dictionary with one array for each key, but the while loop seems to be messing it up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: For future reference: When you write "causes an error", it's very helpful to us if you include the information about what "an error" is, so we don't have to try to guess. You already have that information right in front of you, so there's absolutely no reason to fail to include it in your question. It's to your benefit to give us the relevant information; it helps you get answers more quickly. When posting, please remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind from where we sit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've dimmed an array, it cannot be dimmed again. It can, however, be `ReDim`ed. Dim it outside the loop. If you want to clear the array during each loop, you can do one of the following:

```
ReDim a(1)    ' ReDim without 'Preserve' will clear the array
' or
Erase a
```